# JAI Tiff to JPEG convertion issue

Tags: java, jpeg, tiff, jai

I have an issue converting Tiff-Files to JPEGs with JAI. This is my Code:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        
TIFFDecodeParam param = null;
ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", new FileSeekableStream(inPath), param);
RenderedImage op = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage(0);
        
JPEGEncodeParam jpgparam = new JPEGEncodeParam();
jpgparam.setQuality(67);
ImageEncoder en = ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("jpeg", baos, jpgparam);
en.encode(op);
```

Mostly this code works fine, but with some Images, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Only 1, or 3-band byte data may be written.
at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.JPEGImageEncoder.encode(JPEGImageEncoder.java:142)
```

I cant find any related Problems over here and i have no idea how to fix it. The Images who throw this error have a high Resolution (9000 x 7000 or more) and are mostly scans of old pictures.

Image with this ColorModel works:

```
ColorModel: 
#pixelBits = 24 
numComponents = 3 
color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@21981a50 
transparency = 1 has alpha = false 
isAlphaPre = false
```

This not:

```
ColorModel: 
#pixelBits = 16 
numComponents = 1 
color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@88a30ad 
transparency = 1 has alpha = false 
isAlphaPre = false
```

Comment: I've checked a few of the images. Everyone has a color-depth of 16 bits.

Comment: getNumComponent returns on any image 1

Comment: By any image in meant that any image that fails has 1 band. The others TIfs(which are working regularly) have a 3-band colormodel.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the issue, 1 or 3 byte bands. The 16 bit single channel image would be a single band that takes up more than 1 byte. I am not sure if that is a failure of jpeg or the encoder your using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982651/how-can-i-write-16-bit-grayscale-image-as-jpeg

Comment: So it appears your options are to use a different image encoding (png for example) or to convert your image to an 8 bit grayscale

Comment: T H A N K S! Converting to PNG instead of JPEG works for me.

Comment: Converting tiff to png does not work for me actually.  ```ImageDecoder decoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", seekableStream, null);
RenderedImage[] image = new RenderedImage[1];
image[0] = decoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(0);```  If fails on call to ```decodeAsRenderedImage```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reading the JPEG standard, and it is not readily clear whether this is a limitation of the JPEG format or just the Encoder.

The encoder provide with java only encodes 1 or 3 **byte** bands, so in your case there are 16bit gray scale images. One way to solve this, as it appears you have done, is to save the image using a PNG encoder. It would not support the compression quality parameter.

The other way to handle this would be to save your image as an 8bit gray scale image.

I made a simple example to test this w/out JAI.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(256, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_USHORT_GRAY);
        Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpg");
        while( writers.hasNext() ){
            ImageWriter writer = writers.next();
            ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream( new File("junk.jpg") );
            writer.setOutput(ios);
            writer.write(img);
        }     
    }
```

The simplest way I can see to convert it is to create a new image and draw to it with a graphics.

```
BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
Graphics g = img2.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
g.dispose();
```

Then `img2` can be saved as JPG.